# Migrating Oracle query to PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Can you please help me with this? How can I convert below query to PostgreSQL.

The query below gives different output when executed in PostgreSQL than when executed in Oracle.

```
SELECT 
  to_char(to_date('01011970','ddmmyyyy') + 1/24/60/60 * 4304052,'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') 
from dual;
```

Comment: Try not to tag with irrelevant things. C++ is not a factor here.

Comment: Even in Oracle this is a bad query - adding a *number* to a date and then trying to convert it to a localized string. That number is calculated based on multiple *integer* division which result in 0s and then an integer multiplication that also results in 0

Comment: What does this query try to do in the first place? Convert a Unix timestamp to an actual date? If so, why produce a *string* at the end?

Comment: I have tried by removing the dual but got different value.

Comment: o/p postgresql : to_char
----------------------
 01-jan-1970 00:00:00

Comment: What output are you getting in oracle, and what in postgres? Can you explain what the query is intended to do?

Comment: o/p of oracle :19-feb-1970 19:34:12

Comment: @rekha the problem is the original query itself. If you want to convert a Unix timestamp to a date the *easy* way is to just add the seconds to the epoch [as shown in this possibly duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35613644/convert-unix-timestamp-to-date-and-datetime-sql-oracle): `to_date('01011970','ddmmyyyy')  + numtodsinterval(1456342438,'SECOND')`

Comment: I need postgresql query.As I am trying to Convert from time_t to Postgresql UTC DATE string in c++ code

Comment: In oracle  EXEC SQL SELECT to_char(
            to_date('01011970','ddmmyyyy') + 1/24/60/60 * :dbTimestamp,
            'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' )
            into :dbReceiptTimestamp from dual;

Comment: They are assigning  selected value to a string

Comment: @rekha C++ has nothing to do with Oracle, PostgreSQL or epochs. Besides, even in C++ you *wouldn't* just add seconds, you'd use the appropriate function to convert a timestamp to a date. The query you posted is the *wrong* way to work with Oracle to begin with. If you search for `PostgreSQL convert unix timestamp to date` you'll find many duplicate SO questions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL: how to convert from Unix epoch to date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16609722/postgresql-how-to-convert-from-unix-epoch-to-date)

Comment: As the duplicate shows, the `to_timestamp` converts unix timestamps to dates. ` select to_timestamp( 4304052);` returns `1970-02-19T19:34:12Z`. That's a date value that can be formatted as text if needed

Comment: I got to_timestamp
---------------------------
 1970-02-20 01:04:12+05:30

Comment: how can get the value time_stamp without time zone?

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you want to use the same expression as in Oracle to compute the  resulting value.

The reason it is not working when you simply remove `from dual` is because this expression is being evaluated to `0` as integer division truncates results towards 0.

```
select 1/24/60/60 * 4304052;
 ?column?
----------
        0
(1 row)
```

If I make one of them a decimal, it will give you the required result

```
select 1.0/24/60/60 * 4304052;
          ?column?
-----------------------------
 49.815416666666666347848000
```

Now, after changing this, your expression will return the same result you got in Oracle.

```
SELECT  to_char( to_date('01011970','ddmmyyyy')
 +  INTERVAL '1 DAY' *  (1.0/24/60/60 * 4304052) ,'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') ;
       to_char
----------------------
 19-feb-1970 19:34:12
(1 row)
```

Note that I had to add an interval expression, because unlike Oracle, a Postgres `DATE` does not store time component and simply adding a number to date will result in an error. Using an interval will ensure that it will be evaluated as timestamp.

```
knayak=# select pg_typeof( current_date);
 pg_typeof
-----------
 date
(1 row)

knayak=# select pg_typeof( current_date + INTERVAl '1 DAY');
          pg_typeof
-----------------------------
 timestamp without time zone
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
select '1970-01-01'::date + 4304052 * interval '1 second';
```

You can use `to_char()` to convert this back to a string, if you really want:

```
select to_char('1970-01-01'::date + 4304052 * interval '1 second', 'YYYY-MM-SS HH24:MI:SS');
```